# Telerik RadDock - ajax update returns a JSON error

Tags: ajax, json, telerik, radgrid

Trying to update RadDock (open/close it) by putting it in UpdatePanel however no luck....I'm getting the following response.

```
189|error|500|Invalid JSON primitive: {"Top":179,"Left":583,"DockZoneID":"","Collapsed":false,"Pinned"
```

:false,"Resizable":false,"Closed":false,"Width":"300px","Height":null,"ExpandedHeight":0,"Index":-1}
.|

Here is the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upanelDock" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <telerik:RadDock ID="RadDock1" runat="server" Width="300px">
            <TitlebarTemplate>
                <h2>
                    this is a dock</h2>
            </TitlebarTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                some content here
                <br />
                some content here
                <br />
                some content here
                <br />               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadDock>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnUpdate" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnUpdate_Click">update</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void lbtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.RadDock1.Closed)
        this.RadDock1.Closed = false;
    else
        this.RadDock1.Closed = true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You are not doing anything wrong in your code. I was able to duplicate this problem using both UpdatePanel and RadAjaxManager. According to Telerik support, this is a "limitation" in the RadDock control. More like a bug in my opinion.

Here's what it says in their Support Page Forum: [Non-docked Docks cloned plus Invalid JSON primitive](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/docking/non-docked-docks-cloned-plus-invalid-json-primitive.aspx)

> The RadDock control is not a standard
>   control and there are some limitations
>   when it is updated via ajax. If you
>   want to update a RadDock via ajax you
>   should update all RadDockZones and all
>   RadDocks should be docked.
>
> The error you experience is due to
>   that you update a floating RadDock
>   with AJAX. When dragging the dock you
>   move it outside the update panel and
>   this causes AJAX not working properly
>   as it attempts to recreate the dock at
>   the place it was previously located.
>   In this way two docks with the same id
>   appear on the page and this leads to
>   an exception. This is a common problem
>   for all controls which could be moved
>   in the DOM.

I was able to make your code work by wrapping the RadDock inside a RadDockZone and setting the DockMode property to "Docked". If however, I drag the dock out of the zone, leave it floating and click the "Update" button, the error reappears.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upanelDock" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <telerik:RadDockZone runat="server">
        <telerik:RadDock ID="RadDock1" runat="server" Width="300px" 
                                                      DockMode="Docked">
            <TitlebarTemplate>
                <h2>
                    this is a dock
                </h2>
            </TitlebarTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                some content here
                <br />
                some content here
                <br />
                some content here
                <br />               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadDock>
      </telerik:RadDockZone>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnUpdate" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdate" runat="server"
           OnClick="lbtnUpdate_Click">update</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: i believe i tried it with Telerik's AjaxManager and got same response.

Comment: @dev.e.loper - Please read my updated post. It turns out, you need to wrap the RadDock inside a RadZone and then it only works while it is Docked, not floating.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple RadDocks floating inside a RadDockLayout. Ajax works if I update the RadDock, the RadDockLayout, or the main panel that wraps the RadDockLayout through the RadAjaxManager object.

Ex:

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="mainPanel" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```